# Graphical glitches occuring in Lubuntu

Tags: drivers, graphics, lubuntu, firefox

About a few weeks ago, I began experiencing random graphical glitches and artifacts.

My taskbar or other apps (such as Libreoffice) would get random patches of black, where I would have to mouse over in order to partially fix.

Sometimes when scrolling, the previous frame would remain (think dragging a Windows window when the computer is lagging) and I would again have to mouse over to update.

Also recently, Firefox has been experiencing odd moments where it would begin to flash a frame that happened a second ago.

I'm sorry if I can't provide images, as they happen randomly.

```
System:

Lubuntu LTS 16.04
Intel Pentium N4200 (Intel HD 505 iGPU)
4 GB DDR3 RAM
Firefox 69.0.1
```

Comment: fyi:  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has 5 years of support, flavors like Lubuntu had only 3 years, or from http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/ "*Maintenance updates are provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, Ubuntu Base, and Ubuntu Kylin. All the remaining flavours are supported for 3 years.*"   I'd suggest upgrading to 18.04 if using a flavor, or use the default Ubuntu (Unity) desktop, as parts of your system are no longer supported.

Comment: @guiverc The only issue is that I use Lubuntu because I don't have the most powerful system. Will upgrading to 18.04 break anything?

Comment: If you have a pretty ordinary system, I would expect a clean release-upgrade.  The more additional (non-Ubuntu repo. software you've added like PPAs) the more complex and problems you may expect. Backup your system, (optional: remove all non-Ubuntu software added for >95% success) do the release-upgrade and if you have problems re-install from ISO (thumb-drive) using 'something-else' ensuring 'format' of partitions is **not** selected, your added software will be noted, system directories erased, installed, the your added software put back (if in repos) & reboot. My oldest laptop was a ibm t43